# Sublime How to set new shortcut for a specific feature

Tags: sublimetext, shortcut

In sublime I want to add a feature that if I enter a key combination. I want that combination to produce the following result:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> : put a semicolon at the end of the line and create a new line and put the cursor there.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is quite straightforward. First, create a new file with these contents:

```json
[
    {
        "command": "move_to",
        "args":
        {
            "to": "eol"
        }
    },
    {
        "command": "insert",
        "args":
        {
            "characters": ";\n"
        }
    }
]
```

and save it as `Packages/User/semicolon-newline.sublime-macro` where `Packages` is the directory opened when you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`.

Next, go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings-User` and add the following:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+enter"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/semicolon-newline.sublime-macro"} }
```

This file is JSON-formatted, so if it doesn't have any contents when you open it, surround the line above with square brackets `[ ]`. If there are already entries in it, place the line above at the top (after the opening `[`) and add a comma `,` at the end, after the final closing curly brace `}`.

Save the keybindings file, and you should be all set. This should work with both Sublime Text 2 and 3, on any platform.